# Добавление поддержки языка в IDE от JetBrains

Tags: плагин, ide, jetbrains, angelscript

Мне симпатичен скриптовый язык `AngelScript`, но одна из его проблем - отсутствие поддержки в IDE.

Я бы хотел создать `plugin` для его поддержки в `IDE` основанных на разработках `JetBrains`.

Где можно найти руководства и примеры подобных проектов?

Comment: Смотреть/искать в сторону LSP: https://blog.jetbrains.com/platform/2023/07/lsp-for-plugin-developers/

Comment: В комментариях по ссылке народ возмущается, что только для платных IDE от JetBrains сделана поддержка. В таком случае, можно взять бесплатную VS Code. Для неё массово пилят поддержку разных языков на LSP. И документации много.